# Merging arrays and integers with array_merge() in PHP?

Tags: php, array-merge

I have two arrays and one integer variable:

```
$less = [1, 2, 3];
$pivot = 4;
$great = [5, 6, 7];
```

I tried to use `array_merge()` in different ways:

```
array_merge($less, $pivot, $great);
array_merge($less, [$pivot], $great);
array_merge($less, $pivotArray[] = $pivot, $great);
```

But none of them works.

So the only way to pass an integer to `array_merge()` is to define another array beforehand and then to pass it to the function? Like this:

```
$less = [1, 2, 3];
$pivot = 4;
$great = [5, 6, 7];
$pivotArray[] = $pivot;
array_merge($less, $pivotArray, $great);
```

Comment: What you want to achieve? Expected output?

Comment: You haven't actually said what you want as a result, but assuming you want all the numbers in a single array, [what's wrong with the second option](https://eval.in/1041057)? Are you assigning the result of the `array_merge` calls to anything?

Comment: So the second option actually works fine. I am very sorry. I don't know how that happened to me. I struggled for quite some time with this and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second option with `[$pivot]` should work fine:

```
php > print_r(array_merge($less, [$pivot], $great));
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)
```

Do you have any errors while you doing that?
Also it would be great to have PHP version you use.

Comment: This option actually works fine. I am very sorry. I don't know how that happened to me. I struggled for quite some time with this and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_merge like below:

```
$less = [1, 2, 3];
$pivot = 4;
$great = [5, 6, 7];

$result = array_merge($less, (array)$pivot, $great);
```

Answer (score 0):

even

```
$result = $less + [$pivot] + $great;
```

should do the work

Comment: Why?  Please explain, it will increase it's quality and help new users learning.

Comment: thought its obvious that php will concat arrays while using $array+$array2